# How should I manage password strings in .net?

Tags: .net, security, string, securestring

I know there is the SecureString class, but for most scenarios I don't think it's really useful.

For example, let's say I have a client/server system. The server doesn't need an application made by me, it could be even SQL Server without integrated authentication. When the user enters his password on a form in the client app, it's stored in clear text in memory, so, while I can use a SecureString to read it, I can't really see the point on doing so. Sure, it can reduce the attack surface, but not much... Even if I did, when the user hits 'OK', a plain text string must be generated, even if I just need to compute a hash from it.

So, is there anyway to avoid the password strings to float around until the GC decides to reclaim the memory? Even then, would the memory get erased before it's used again?

Comment: what is the statement of the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: if you want a more secure applcation then use integrated authentication

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I want to be able to use the contents of a SecureString in a secure way.

Comment: That seems more a description of a perceived solution to another problem...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Ok, second try. I am building a client/server system. We plan to integrate some open standard for authentication, but for now it's handmade. I have a good solution (or so I think) for the password interchange through the network. My only problem right now is the hash thing already stated: I need to compute a hash from the password, and for that, I need the password in clear text. Perhaps the solution given by dbemerlin is not as bad as it seemed to me at first glance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SecureString` is a great idea whose time has not quite arrived. It is most useful in the following scenario:

1. Your presentation layer password box grabs each keypress individually and stuffs them into a `SecureString` one at a time. The class exposes several mutating methods specifically designed to facilitate this. For example, WPF supports this (via the [PasswordBox.SecurePassword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.passwordbox.securepassword.aspx) control property).
2. Your authentication API accepts passwords of type `SecureString` natively.

If either of these is untrue, then you are pretty much wasting your time, since at some point in the code path you will be forced to unpack the `SecureString` into a `String`.

The safest way to authenticate a user is always to avoid handling username/password credentials altogether. You could use Windows authentication, InfoCards, OpenID, etc instead.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it's the most complete answer, although after thinking about it, I like a lot the dbemerlin suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the hash key by key. Just use the OnKeyPress Event of the textbox and then calculate the hash with that additional byte and enter some other character like `*` into the textbox.

Comment: So what? I'll need to have an immutable byte array with each password byte in plain text, anyway.